SharePoint authentication using a certificate and http POST method
Recent changes (circa. 2024-09-09) implemented by Microsoft are preventing my script from authenticating with SharePoint Online (SPO) using a username and password. I believe I now have to do the authentication using a certificate. However, I am unsure how to utilise a certificate in the context of my script.
And while my script is written in R, I don't want that to be a distraction from what is otherwise vanilla REST 1.0 webs calls using HTTP GET/POST methods. Hence the issue is not R-specific and applicable to any language that can work with URLs and HTTP.
In overview my script:

Requests a security token from SPO using a username and password via a HTTP POST method to https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf.
Requests an access token from my SharePoint tenancy domain using the "rtFA" and "FedAuth" values of the Binary Security token returned by the previous call, using a HTTP post method to, as example, https://{mytenancy}.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0
Use the access token returned by the previous call for all subsequent REST calls, typically which are HTTP GET methods; as example the following to return the item count of a library etc. https://{mytenancy}.sharepoint.com/sites/{mySiteColl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My Library Title')/ItemCount

Perhaps it is naive but I'm hoping that by simply changing the initial http POST method to incorporate a certificate, the rest of my script will work without change. However, I'm unsure how to change that initial POST.
My current request body to https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf is a SOAP XML envelope that I've included below:


<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
            xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
                    xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:UsernameToken>
                <o:Username>username@mytenacy.com</o:Username>
                <o:Password>thisismypassword</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
            <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                <a:EndpointReference>
                    <a:Address>mytenacy.sharepoint.com</a:Address>
                </a:EndpointReference>
            </wsp:AppliesTo>
            <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
            <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
            <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
        </t:RequestSecurityToken>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>



Now according to Copilot, I would need to change my SOAP envelope as below to utilise a certificate, with some instructions on how to replace the JWT value specific to my certificate. However, I don't know if this is correct, and can find no useful reference to confirm:


<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
            xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
                    xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2024-09-13T07:46:58Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2024-09-13T07:51:58Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"
                                   ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/SCT"
                                   EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
                <!-- Insert your signed JWT here -->
                eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjE2MjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjYifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3NoYXJlcG9pbnQuY29tIiwiaXNzIjoieW91ci1jbGllbnQtaWQiLCJzdWIiOiJ5b3VyLWNsaWVudC1pZCIsImV4cCI6MTYyNjY2NjY2NiwiaWF0IjoxNjI2NjY2NjY2fQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
            </o:BinarySecurityToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
            <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                <a:EndpointReference>
                    <a:Address>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</a:Address>
                </a:EndpointReference>
            </wsp:AppliesTo>
            <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
            <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
        </t:RequestSecurityToken>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>



While I am still awaiting to get an app registered and be issued a certificate, I have have no confidence or way of knowing whether the modified SOAP envelope will actually work. And even then it will be a matter of trial and error; though it it is error I may be stuck indefinitely.
Can anyone advise how to form a valid POST request to authenticate against SPO using a certificate? (and please note I'm not competent in other programming languages and will need it explained in context of vanilla http methods).
